# How do I resolve one argument passed to a subroutine defined to accept 2 parameters in Perl

Tags: perl, subroutine

I am creating a new object as follows:

```
my $new_obj = new P_module({key => 'abc'});
```

The P_module has a constructor defined as follows:

```
sub new {
    my ($pkg, $input) = @_;
    my $obj = {};
    bless ($obj, ref($pkg)||$pkg);
    $obj->{key} = $input->{key};
 }
```

From what I have read, since a hash is being passed as argument to new, it will be represented as a 2-element array. So, `pkg` should be `key` and `input` should be `abc`. Then, how does `obj` come to hold a key `key` and what does `$input->{key}` even mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all,

```
my $new_obj = new P_module({ key => 'abc' });
```

is better written as

```
my $new_obj = P_module->new({ key => 'abc' });
```

This is short for

```
my %anon = ( key => 'abc' );
my $new_obj = P_module->new(\%anon);
```

---

When making a method call, the invocant (what's left of the `->`) is passed as the first argument. That means `$pkg` is the string `P_module`, and `$input` is the reference returned by `{ key => 'abc' }`.

Since `$input` is a reference to a hash, `$input->{key}` gets the value of the element with key `key` from the referenced hash.

---

How I would have written this:

```
sub new {
    my ($class, %args) = @_;
    my $self = bless({}, $class);      # If base class.
    #my $self = $class->SUPER::new();  # If inheriting.
    $self->{key} = $args{$key};
    return $self;
 }

 my $obj = P_module->new( key => 'abc' );
```

There's no need for a hash in the caller, and there's no reason to support `$existing_obj->new`. It also uses more standard names `$class` and `$self`.

Comment: Thanks so very much. That was a very helpful explanation :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a reason that you have this:

```
bless ($obj, ref($pkg)||$pkg);
```

instead of this?

```
bless ($obj, $pkg);
```

If not, then I'm assuming you cut & pasted it from some other code somewhere.  What you probably want is the latter.

That `ref($pkg)||$pkg` allows you to do this:

```
my $new_object = $existing_obj->new;
```

instead of

```
my $new_object = new Classname;
```

Since you probably don't need to do that, then just stick with

```
bless ($obj, $pkg);
```

Comment: I agree. In the unlikely event that you needed `$existing_obj->new`, you could still use `ref($existing_obj)->new`. This (and a separate `clone` constructor if cloning is required) is far cleaner, as far as I'm concerned. That said, this answer is a really a comment, and I would mark it as such.

Comment: If the comment system allowed the space and formatting necessary to make a detailed explanation, I would have made it a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The surrounding curly braces create a hash *reference* or hashref, which is a single scalar. The argument values will be

- `$pkg` — the name of the containing package, likely `"P_module"`
- `$input` — reference to the supplied hash

The code `$input->{key}` accesses the value associated with the key `"key"`, which is supplied by the caller with

```
my $new_obj = new P_module({key => 'abc'});
```

It is considered better style to write this as

```
my $new_obj = P_module->new({key => 'abc'});
```

You might add another key, as in

```
my $new_obj = P_module->new({key => 'abc', other => 'unused'});
```

The value associated with `"key"` gets copied into the object’s state with

```
$obj->{key} = $input->{key};
```

Note that Perl subroutines return the value of the last expression, so your code has a bug. You want the last line of `P_module::new` to be

```
bless ($obj, ref($pkg)||$pkg);
```

Because that will return the blessed object that can then be used to call other methods, *e.g.*,

```
my $new_obj = new P_module({key => 'abc'});
print $new_obj->other_method_that_you_must_define(), "\n";
```

Comment: I didn't consider that. I only posted the code that I couldn't explain. Thanks for pointing out the error though.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a method the object itself is passed behind the scenes; or, if the sub uses [bless](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/bless.html) then it is the constructor and the class name is passed instead.  So any method receives that, the object or the class name, as its first argument. The rest are arguments explicitly passed to the method.

You pass a *hash reference* `{...}`, what is a scalar. So that is assigned to `$input`, given that the "quitely" passed class name is assigned to `$pkg`.

The constructor for that interface, with a hash reference, is most customarily and simply written as

```
sub new {
    my ($class, $input) = @_;
    my $self = { %$input };
    return bless $self, $class;
}
```

where `return` may be omitted since the return of the last evaluated statement is returned. The last two lines can be written as `return bless { %$input }, $class;`, and an (anonymous) hashref is initialized, blessed into its package `$class` (so it's an object), and returned.

Note that you don't have to pass a hashref; a plain hash makes for cleaner interface.  A reference need be used if there may be yet other arguments, 
to make it possible to parse all that.

However, you normally want to process arguments. For one, you **must** check that they conform to what your class supports, and not just blindly assign the keys passed by a user to the attributes. Then work out defaults if you provide them, check values if you need to, etc.

This initialization of data is sometimes split into a separate subroutine.  For example

```
sub new {
    my ($class, $input) = @_;
    my $self = {};
    bless $self, $class;       # $self is an object now
    $self->_init($input);      # on which methods can be called
    return $self;
}

sub _init {
    my ($self, $args) = @_;
    # Check arguments, work out defaults (etc), 
    # then assign to self as appropriate
    %$self = %$args;
}
```

where the code writes "back" via reference so that `$self` in `new` is updated.

This should be used with the normal method invocation

```
my $new_obj = P_module->new({key => 'abc', other => '...'});
```

and **not** using *indirect notation* `new P_module`.  The constructor, mostly called `new` (merely by custom – you can call it what you want), is a normal sub special only because it `bless`es a reference (normally a hash reference) and is thus passed the class name instead of the object. Thus it "knows" its package and is an object.

Literature: [perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Perl-Modules) (a class is a package), tutorial [perlootut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html), and reference [perlobj](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html).

Once you get comfortable with Perl's built-in object-oriented facilities, what I recommend doing, there are many modules that make all this (and much more) easier to do.

The first to recommend are the very modern [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/Moose-2.2006/lib/Moose.pm) and its light-weight counterpart [Moo](http://search.cpan.org/~haarg/Moo-2.003002/lib/Moo.pm).

Comment: `my $self = my $self = { %$input }; return bless $self, $class;` is more simply written `return bless { %$input }, $class;`

Comment: @ikegami   I pulled back from showing yet more compact ways (I had that exact form already typed), given the basic purpose of this.  But it's tempting ... added.  Thank you for the edit.